# Instance vs class variables and type hinting

Tags: python, python-typing

I am confused by how Python is expecting me to do type hinting for instance and class variables.

Both [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar) and [the mypy cheatsheet](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#classes) (according to my understanding, at least) state that such type hinting should work as in the code below.

```py
from typing import ClassVar


class A:
    x: ClassVar[int] = 1  # class variable
    y: int = 2  # instance variable


# This should and does work:
print(A.x)

# If y was really an instance variable, then the following should
# a) not work and/or b) at least show a type issue -- but it does
# neither:
print(A.y)

# y is clearly a class variable:
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
print(a1.y, a2.y)
A.y = 3
print(a1.y, a2.y)
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, if Python really treated `y` as an instance variable, accessing `A.y` should produce an error in my view. Or what am I missing here?

So maybe this is *only* about type checking and not about the functionality itself? That would be questionable in my view because it is highly confusing. But even if that was the case I would at least expect mypy to produce some warning where `A.y` gets accessed but it doesn't, `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`, so clearly I am missing something.

Comment: You're assigning a value to `y`, so it _is_ a class attribute. If you actually wanted an instance attribute, it should just be `y: int`.

Comment: You are *hinting* it as an instance variable, but you are in fact creating a class variable

Comment: If `y` gets initialized as part of the class definition, then it's by definition a class variable (whether or not you annotate it that way).  I always just add the annotation inside `__init__` if needed and don't have any declaration/annotation for instance variables at the class level (with the exception of dataclasses).  I didn't even know `ClassVar` existed; annotating class attributes works just fine without it in my experience.

Comment: Should there be a warning by the type checker or the linter for these kinds of situations? I.e., a clearly defined class variable (x in the example above) mixed with an "implicit" class variable (= not defined as class variable and therefore seemingly an instance variable but still considered a class variable due to the assignment; y in the example)? Seems quite likely to me to run into this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You don't initialize instance variables outside the constructor. What you're doing is accidentally making `y` *both* a class variable and an instance variable. Consider

```
class A:
    x: ClassVar[int] = 1  # class variable
    y: int  # instance variable

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.y = 2
```

Comment: You *can* initialize instance variables outside of the constructor, although, definitely not in the class body.